# Finding the frequency of each word in a file

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the frequency of each word in a file.

Not just searching for how many instances of a certain word there are, but the frequency of each word.

For example, if the file contained this sentence:

> "Super awesome super cool people are awesome!"

It would output this:

```
Super - 2
Awesome - 2
Cool - 1
People - 1
Are - 1
```

Showing the frequency of each word.

How can I do this in Java, but counting the entire file, and not knowing what words that I might be testing?

Comment: You have two separate questions here. Split them as such. Use a `Map<String, Integer>`, checking if the map has an entry for the String token. If it does, add 1 to the count, otherwise set it to 1.

Comment: To see an HTML page's text without markup, use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). The HtmlPage class has an [asText()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/DomNode.html#asText%28%29) method.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
// This will match all non-word characters, i.e. characters that are
// not in [a-zA-Z_0-9]. This should match whitespaces and interpunction.
String nonWordDelimiter="[\W]+";

String[] words = text.split(nonWordDelimiter);

Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String word : words) {
    if (!word.isEmpty()) {
        Integer frequency = frequencies.get(word);

        if (frequency == null) {
            frequency = 0;
        }

        ++frequency;
        frequencies.put(word, frequency);
    }
}
```

Finally, the map `frequencies` will contain the frequency of each word.